# NVIDIA GPU Ubuntu Support

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games

Quick question.

I'm building a workstation at present (based on: i7, 16GB, 120SSD, ASUS Mobo).

My question is really to do with GPU support. I'm considering something from the Nvidia range (750) but would like some idea how well Ubuntu supports all the "bells and whistles" of these modern GPU's. Apologies if this has been covered already, but information online specific to Ubuntu from real users would be very much appreciated.

I intend to use Steam (for gaming) and graphics apps (aka: Gimp, Inskape, Blender and Scribus).

Thanks in advance,
M

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia has decent support in Linux, they have [drivers for Linux](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/76884/en-us) (both 32 and 64 bits).

If you want CUDA support probably you will have to use the proprietary drivers, otherwise you can use [nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org).

Just to let you know, here is the list of supported GeForce 700 based cards from the official driver (version 340.24, dated 2014.7.8):

> GeForce 700 Series:
>
> GeForce GTX TITAN Z, GeForce GTX TITAN Black, GeForce GTX TITAN, GeForce GTX 780 Ti, GeForce GTX 780, GeForce GTX 770, GeForce GTX 760, GeForce GTX 760 Ti (OEM), GeForce GTX 750 Ti, **GeForce GTX 750**, GeForce GTX 745, GeForce GT 740, GeForce GT 730

Comment: Thanks for that. I have found a card that fits my budget and is also on the 700 series list. Happy times ;)